# How to take the smallest id of a table with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I look for the way to take the smallest id of a city to avoid an error in my unitarian test. After try, I have this error:

> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 62:
>
> Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AS'

```
public function testDB()
{
    $id = $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:City')
        ->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where("MIN(b.id) AS id")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$id = $qb
        ->select('city.id')
        ->from('AppBundle:City', 'city')
        ->orderBy('city.id', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

You can also use `getSingleScalarResult` instead if `getResult`  to get only one single scalar result

Comment: glad to help you @Paul

Comment: Use `getSingleScalarResult()` to avoid array result?

Comment: Yes it could be a good practice, I have use getResult because OP used that function

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$id = $qb
    ->select('MIN(city.id) AS id')
    ->from('AppBundle:City', 'city');
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer always requires some explanation on how/why it helps.

Comment: I agree with you but here it's just a small change that is deducted.